# An intuitive question about the metric $d(\cdot,\cdot)$ on a complete Riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

Let $(M,g)$ be a complete Riemannian manifold. Suppose $\gamma_1,\gamma_2:[0,1] \to M$ are two different segments(i.e.minimizing geodesics) from $p$ to $x=\exp_p(v)$. Suppose further that $\gamma'_1(1)+\gamma'_2(1)\neq 0$, and thus we can find some $w\in T_xM$ such that $g(w,\gamma'_i(1))< 0$ (Intuitively,$w$ forms an angle $> 90^{\circ}$ with each $\gamma'_i(1)$, $i=1,2$ ).

Now, we select a curve $c:[0,\epsilon) \to M$ with $c(0)=x$ and $c'(0)=w$. I would like to ask how to show that $d(p,c(s))<d(p,x)$ for any $0<s<\epsilon$.
Please help. Thanks!
[image]

Comment: Look up the first variation formula.for length.

Comment: @JackLee : and do we really need $g$ to compare the direction of $w$ and $\gamma_1'$ ? (and do we really need $\gamma_2$ ?)

Comment: @user1952009: It's important that the angle between $w$ and $\gamma_i'$ be obtuse, and you need a metric to compute angles.

Comment: @JackLee : aren't $w$ and $\gamma_1'$ vectors of $T_xM$ ? can't we consider some locally orthogonal local coordinates or something like that for comparing $w$ and $\gamma_1'$  ?

Comment: @user1952009: Yes, they are. But you still need a metric to compute the angle between them.

Comment: @JackLee : so you say that $g(\gamma_1',w) < 0$ is exactly the condition for the distance to $p$ being diminishing on $c(s)$ ? and $g(\gamma_1',w) > 0$ would mean it increases ? this is what I feel difficult to see. wait I got it, $g(.,.)$ is positive definite hence yes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38473/discussion-between-jack-lee-and-user1952009).

Comment: This is not true as stated - the curve $c$ could double back on itself and go past $x$ in the other direction. You can only guarantee that $d(p,c(s))<d(p,x)$ for $s$ in some $(0,\delta)$, where $\delta < \epsilon$ depends on $c$.

Comment: @AnthonyCarapetis   Thanks. But the argument here is partly from Petersen's Riemannian Geometry(second edition,GTM171), page 142, Lemma 16(Klingenberg); so it may not likely to be completely wrong.

Comment: I'm guessing all you need is for it to be true for small $s$, which is what you should get from the first variation formula.

Comment: Agree. Personally, the point should be how to use the strange conditions when we compute the distance.